# Is it possible to fix Windows altered case of file names with pull from remote git repo?

Tags: windows, git, restore

I have a problem where a Windows file restore changed the case of *some* file names.  This causes a trainwreck with some projects.

Fortunately these projects are pushed to remote git servers.  The remotes are up to date with origin/master, and cloning the projects is a solution.  The only problem with that is the time-consuming task of replacing git-ignored files and dealing with other updates.

An ideal solution would be to pull down all files from the remote, overwriting the files in the origin/master.  Is this possible?  How do I force a pull down or merge, even though they are already a match.  I want to keep it that way, just use git to rewrite the correct file name cases.

`git pull` or `git pull -f` results in `Already up-to-date.`

Answer (score 0):

First, set git to be case sensitive. By default this was set true to match Windows:

`git config core.ignorecase false`

Check the list of changed-case file names Windows messed up.  At the very least, this is your list of files to fix:

`git status`

Now, delete the files and folders that are messed up. **Do not delete git ignored files!**  Files in .gitignore must be fixed the hard way.

Now, get your deleted files back as they were before Windows changed the case:

`git checkout .`

Yet another reason to quit Windows.